# Reverse and forward doubling identity in Fibonacci sequence $\text{mod 9}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, multisets

Fibonacci sequence ($\mathbb{F}$) has a repeating cycle known as Pisano number $\pi\text{(x)}$ , when $mod \text{ x}$ is applied upon the sequence. Length of the cycles can be found from: http://oeis.org/A001175

With $\text{mod 9}$ cycle length $\pi\text{(9)}$ is $24$, so the repeating 24-tuple would be:

$$\mathbb{S} = \mathbb{F}_{n < 25} \text{ mod }9 = (0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 4, 3, 7, 1, 8, 0, 8, 8, 7, 6, 4, 1, 5, 6, 2, 8, 1)$$

There are several doubling sub sequences inside $\mathbb{S}$. For example:

$$\mathbb{S}_{4n-5} = (1,2,4,8,7,5)$$

and reverse of it:

$$\mathbb{S}_{4n+1} = (5,7,8,4,2,1)$$

On the other hand doubling multiset is:

$$\mathbb{D} = 2^n = [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,...]$$

Now my attention is on the fact that the doubling sequence $\text{mod 9}$ also happens to have a same repeating 6-tuple with $\mathbb{S}_{4n-5}$, namely:

$$\mathbb{D}_{n<6} \text{ mod 9}= (1,2,4,8,7,5) = \mathbb{S}_{4n-5}$$

So my question is if this forward and reverse doubling subsequence inside the Fibonacci $\text{mod 9}$ sequence is purely mathematical coincidence or if it can be explained by some moderate algebra?

#### References:

http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/fibonacci/fib.htm

#### Chart for visualization

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Given $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, the minimal polynomial of $\varphi^4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is given by
$$ q(x) = x^2-7x+1 \equiv (x+1)^2 \pmod{9} $$
hence it follows that for any $k\in[1,4]$, the sequences defined by $G_{n}=F_{4n+k}$ behave like:
$$ G(n) \equiv (-1)^n\cdot\left( A+Bn\right) \pmod{9}.$$
In particular,
$$ F_{4n+1}\equiv (-1)^n (1+3n)\pmod{9},\qquad F_{4n-5}\equiv (-1)^n (-4+3n)\pmod{9} $$
that easily explains your reversing property.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Jack-Daurizio. Can you please elaborate few parts of the answer so that I can understand it better: what does minimal polynomial mean in this context and why phi^4? Is Q refering to q(x)? What are G, A, and B standing for? And where do you get $(-1)^n(1+3n)$?

Comment: I further used your formula to retrieve other 2 sequences in the Fibonacci sequence $\text{ mod 9}$: $\{(-1)^n(1+3n) \text{ mod 9}, (-1)^n*8 \text{ mod 9},  (-1)^n(-4+3n) \text{ mod 9}, (-1)^n(6+3n) \text{ mod 9}\} \text{ when n = } \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} => \{\{5, 7, 8, 4, 2, 1\}, \{1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8\}, \{1, 2, 4, 8, 7, 5\}, \{0, 3, 3, 0, 6, 6\}\}$, but it is still unclear to me, how it connects with $F_{f(n)} \text{ mod 9}$...