# How to prove that three different modulo 9 equations results the same sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, fibonacci-numbers, proof-explanation

First let index sequence $ℕ_0=(0,1,2,…)$ and $n∈\mathbb{N}_{0}$.

Then let:

$$S_a = (-1)^n(a+bn) \text{ mod 9 } \text{ where } a = 1\text{, } b = -3$$

$$S_b = 2^n \text{ mod 9 }$$

$$S_c = F_{a+bn} \text{ mod 9 } \text{ where } a = -1\text{, } b = 4$$

where $F_{a+bn}$ is referring to the Fibonacci sequence a.k.a. $\{(...,-2,-1,-1,)0,1,1,2,3,5,8,...\}$.

I want to know proving procedure for:

$$S_a = S_b = S_c$$

in a hope to see the relation between three different functions for the sequences. Inductively I have found these sequences to be same, if $n=(0,1,2,3,4,5)$, then:

$$S_a = S_b = S_c = (1,2,4,8,7,5)$$

Note: my question is related to the former open question: [Reverse and forward doubling identity in Fibonacci sequence $\text{mod 9}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826159/reverse-and-forward-doubling-identity-in-fibonacci-sequence-textmod-9)

Comment: Just so we're clear, it's $F_{-1}=1$, $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, and $F_2=1$, correct?

Comment: Oh yes, we are talking about normal Fibonacci sequence, right.

Comment: For $S_a$ and $n=0$, I'm getting $(-1)(1-3(0)) \equiv -1 \equiv 8 \pmod 9$ which is not the same as $S_b$ and $S_c$. Are you sure it's not supposed to be the following? $$S_a=(-1)^n(a+bn) \pmod 9$$

Comment: Again, correct. I missed power n from the equation. Now fixed on the OP.